# Detecting if the app is running on the Virtual Android Environment apps like Virtual Android & VPhoneGaGa

Tags: android, android-developer-api

Through *'filesDir.path'* we can easily detect cloning apps like Dual Space, Multi Space, and Parallel space apps. Detection of the virtual environments offers by Xiamoi devices, One Plus and Samsung devices are also possible by *'filesDir.path'*.

Recently I come across these two apps [Virtual Android - Game Emulator & Dual Space](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.pspace.vandroid&hl=en&gl=US) and [VPhoneGaGa](https://gsxnj.cn/index/). They claim that their apps create an independent virtual operating system on users' devices.

filesDir.path solution doesn't work on these apps. When my app runs on the virtual environment by these apps, the fileDir.path returns the original file path as if no  there is no middle app in between.

I want to detect and block my app to run in these virtual environments.  I didn't find any working solution other than searching for systems apps: Gmail, Maps, Youtube, etc.

Comment: were you able to find any solution for this?

Comment: still no solutions?